# Jquery Ui Sortable Divs Disapear

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When I sort anything above the first div it disappears.

Here is a live version of the code http://hanontest.com/default4.aspx (sorry about the design, its just test code.)

If you sort anything above the "Drive To" div it will disappear.

Using

```
Bootstrap.Css
JqueryUITheme.css
Jquery.js 
JqueryUI.js
```

Any ideas? I did some searching but found nothing really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to happen because of this:

```
style="float: left; position: relative;"
```

When your drag the form to the first div that style is added to them, like this:

```
<div id="FormLunch" class="list-group-item ui-sortable-handle" style="float: left; position: relative;">
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I removed the Float Left from all the sortable divs and it now works.